# Node.js/child_process: I am having trouble successfully killing a given process to allow me to delete the given directory

Tags: node.js, typescript, child-process, spawn

The following code is meant to kill a given process and allow me to remove a directory and update it:

```
    private async updateRepo(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            log.standard("Updating repo...");
            if (this.active[this.repo]) {
                while (!this.killed) {
                    this.active[this.repo].kill("SIGINT");
                    rmSync(`${__dirname}/scripts/${this.repo}`, { force: true, recursive: true });
                };
                delete this.active[this.repo];
                await this.addRepo();
            };
        } catch(e) {
            log.error(`Error updating ${this.repo}!`, e);
        };
    };
```

The following code is how I deploy and establish a given process:

```
    private deploy(): void {
        try {
            log.standard(`Deploying ${this.repo}...`);
            const thread = spawn(`${process.platform === "win32" ? "npm.cmd" : "npm"} install && ${process.platform === "win32" ? "npm.cmd" : "npm"} ${process.env.COMMAND != "" ? process.env.COMMAND : "start"}`, { cwd: `${__dirname}/scripts/${this.repo}`, shell: true });
            log.success(`Successfully deployed ${this.repo}!`);
            thread.stdout.on("data", (data: string) => {
                this.active[this.repo] = thread;
                log.repo(this.repo, data.toString());
            });
            thread.on("close", async () => {
                this.killed = true;
                log.standard(`${this.repo} has been killed!`);
            });
            thread.stderr.on("data", (data: string) => {
                log.repo(this.repo, data.toString());
            });
        } catch(e) {
            log.error(`Error deploying ${this.repo}!`, e);
        };
    };
```

`this.active` being of type `active: Record<string, ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams> = {};`.

On update my code is freezing on kill and not killing the process this is the output:

```
[LOG] 20:53:29 Checking for test-repo updates...
[LOG] 20:53:29 Update detected for test-repo!
[LOG] 20:53:29 Updating repo...
```

What I'm not understanding is why a given process cannot be promptly killed properly without freezing because I cannot remove the directory and update it without the given process being killed.

Comment: You have a synchronous `while` loop that keeps spinning without giving the `close` event listener that would clear `this.killed` a chance to run.

Comment: What do you mean? Within the given while loop I am killing the process which in itself ends the while loop.

Comment: No, killing the process does not synchronously fire the `close` event. It tells the OS to kill the process, which will lead to the pipe being closed, which will *schedule* a `close` event. But it never is dispatched until your code yields control back to the event loop.